# jQuery .each only appends the last JS obj element into divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, foreach

I have some dynamically-created divs that each contain a Title. Clicking on a div opens a modal (that's emptied upon click), and the Title also appears in the modal a second time. I'm trying to append the category descriptions into the modals, but only the last JS obj's element is appended. For instance, by clicking on the div titled "Animals" the modal pops up and I should see the description "Animals are...". Clicking on a different div should load a modal with a different description.

I can see all of the elements in the console, so I'm not sure why I'm running into this issue---I believe something's missing from `$.each`, but I'm not sure what.

#### JS snippet:

```
// axios code here

loadCategories(){
        let categs = _categories

// down below I'm duplicating the template to create one div for each category
        let $host = $("#host");
            for (var i = 0; i < categs.length; i++) {
                let $template = $("#template").clone();

                $("#cat-title").empty();
                $("#cat-title").append(categs[i].Title);

                $("#cat-box-id").attr("data-category", categs[i].Title);

                $host.append($template.html());
                console.log('catdesc ' + categs[i].Description) // does show everything

            }

        $.each(categs, function(i, val) {
             $("#category-desc").empty();
             $("#category-desc").append(val.Description);
        })
```

#### HTML snippet:

```
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="category-desc" id="category-desc"></div>
        </div>
```

#### JS obj sample:

```
{
    "d": {
      "results": [
        {
          "Title": "Animals",
          "Description": "Animals are multicellular eukaryotic organisms that form the biological kingdom Animalia. With few exceptions, animals consume organic material, breathe oxygen, are able to move, can reproduce sexually, and grow from a hollow sphere of cells, the blastula, during embryonic development. Over 1.5 million living animal species have been described\u2014of which around 1 million are insects\u2014but it has been estimated there are over 7 million animal species in total.",
          "SortOrder": null
        },
        {
          "Title": "Colors",
          "Description": "Color (American English), or colour (Commonwealth English), is the characteristic of human visual perception described through color categories, with names such as red, orange, yellow, green, blue, or purple.",
          "SortOrder": null
        },
// other data
        {
          "Title": "World Capitals",
          "Description": "A capital city (or simply capital) is the municipality exercising primary status in a country, state, province, or other administrative region, usually as its seat of government.",
          "SortOrder": null
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you empty your `#category-desc` before append new value, that why it appends only the last value.

```
$.each(categs, function(i, val) {
  // $("#category-desc").empty();
  // ^ ^ don't empty content if you want value to be append 
  $("#category-desc").append(val.Description);
})
```

Comment: Hi @radonirina-maminiaina, if I remove the `.empty` it appends all of the category descriptions next to each other.

Comment: So you need to filter your category, only store the category you want to display into your element